# Docker understanding

Tags: docker

I have following images inside my docker registry:

[image]

Lets assume that file-finder image is derived from ls_files. If so, can I tell that file-finder shares 996MB of disk storage with ls_files image and has only 58,72MB of his own storage?

Comment: You seem to have attached a PNG file to the question; that's not something I can easily search for or run.  Do you have a textual listing of the registry contents, or the original Dockerfiles?  (Commands like `docker images` don't list the contents of external registries, and their `SIZE` column is the total size of all layers, possibly double-counting shared layers.)

Comment: Yea, its clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you assumption is incorrect.

I think your `Dockerfile` is probably like this:

```
FROM ls_files
RUN # Your commands, etc.
```

Then you run:

```
docker build -t file-finder:1.0.0 .
```

Now the image `file-finder` is a complete and stand-alone image. You can remove `ls_files` with no issue since the image `ls_files` is now included and downloaded into the `file-finder` image.

When you build an image on top of another, the base image then has nothing to do with the new image and you can remove the base.

**Example**

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add nginx
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off"]
```

Let us run:

```
docker build -t my_nginx:1 .
```

Now let us remove `alpine:latest` image.

```
docker image rm alpine:latest
```

Now let's run `my_nginx:1` image and you should see no error.